# Why do I need to be "sudo" to run the Moovweb server?

Tags: moovweb

I've downloaded the Moovweb SDK and installed it on my computer.

I ran `moov login` and entered in my credentials.

I generated a project using `moov generate example example.com`

Why do I need to type `sudo moov server --auto-hosts` ?

What is it doing that it needs super user access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that root access to run service that uses port 80, or any port below 1024.

This is **linux kernel security feature**.

More detailed information:

["Why can only root listen to ports below 1024?" at Mikael Ståldal’s blog](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2007/10/31/why-can-only-root-listen-to-ports-below-1024/)

---

Solution 1:

If you don't want to enter root password everytime or automate that kind of task by script - learn to use `sudoers`.

[HowTO: Sudoers Configuration at ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821)

---

Solution 2:

Port limit is defined in kernel source, in `include/net/sock.h` file.

```
/* Sockets 0-1023 can't be bound to unless you are superuser */
#define PROT_SOCK       1024
```

To change this on your desktop (not recommended on servers) - you may compile new kernel, with `PORT_SOCK` set to `79` to unlock 80 port for non-root users, or set it to `0` to unlock all ports.

Answer (score 1):

It launches the server in the ports `80` or `443` which requires root privileges to do so.